# Name of the song that plays in Boruto Episode 100 after opening theme?

Tags: music, boruto

I was watching Boruto episode 100 today and really want to know the music name that plays around 3:00 to 4:25.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the song myself by researching a bit on Youtube. It is called "Growth of a Child" OST Boruto. Enjoy.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4vR4Z2YNT8